# Why a continuous function which goes $∞$ when $x→±∞$ has minimum value?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Let $f(x)$ be a real function.
If $x$ is continuous on $(-∞,∞)$ and $f(x)→∞$ when $x→±∞$, then how to prove that $f(x)$ has minimum value?

I think if I could prove $f(x)$ is continuous at $∞$, the proof finishes using the fact that every continuous function on a compact set has a minimum value.

Comment: Using your idea prove that $e^{-f(x)}$ has a maximum.

Comment: Could you tell me what wrong with that？For example taking f(x)　to be x^2, I could not find anything wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $N$ be the minimal value of $f$ in $[0,1]$, which exists by compactness. Choose $M$ such that for $\lvert x \rvert > M$ we have $\lvert f(x) \rvert > N$. The minimum of $f$ is then attained in $[-M,M]$.